# Allow IAM User to access API Gateway Execute API on another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, api-gateway

I have `AWS Account A` (billing account) and `AWS account B` (dev account). I have API Gateway endpoints deployed in account B and has aws iam as authoriser.
I would like a user from account A to be able to execute API deployed in account B.

I know I can achieve this by attaching the Resource Policy in account B. If possible, I would like to do this via the IAM role attached to the user in account A.

The user in account A can already assume an admin role in account B. I would have thought that this would get them access already. But it's not.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your resource policy on the API gateway?

Comment: I don't have any resource policy attached. I want to achieve this just with iam policy attached to the user.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to do. Without API resource-policy, your API gateway is public. Or you are taking about private API in a VPC?

Comment: The api has aws iam as authoriser. I missed that part in the original question. I have updated it.